# Ubuntuone-indicator icon missing in XFCE4 bar

Tags: ubuntu-one, xfce

I know for a fact that before I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 from 11 the `ubuntuone-indicator` icon worked just fine. I upgraded to the new Ubuntu and XFCE4 instead of Gnome and now the icon is a **nothing** icon for the `ubuntuone-indicator` app in my bar.

[image]

It use to be the little cloud icon, now nothing. I have not removed anything from Gnome at all, all Gnome components are still installed, I just switched to XFCE instead.

So what gives with this? Any ideas?

I tried a fresh install after purging it, cleaning and autocleaning then install once more. It of course installed to the new location under `lib` but still no icon.

Comment: Hi @jfreak53 , are you still having this issue?

Comment: Yep, also with another program as well as Ubu one.

Comment: I have no specific suggestion as of now, as I am also looking up for a convincing answer. In the meanwhile, I hope you have kept all your softwares and packages up to date, just to ensure we do not miss on any fix delivered by that route.

Comment: I had problems with the network manager showing up as well as the power-indicator. I stumbled over a solution and documented it here: http://askubuntu.com/a/572117/367444 . If this is still open, you may want to see if it helps.