# How to display network manager icon on the Xfce panel?

Tags: network-manager, icons, xfce

I installed Xfce in Ubuntu 14.04, but the network manager icon disappeared. When I run `sudo nm-applet`, the icon shows. Not only the network manager but also the power manager and fcitx icon disappeared. fcitx is a Chinese input method.

Comment: Do you have both Notification Area and Indicator Plugin on your panel? http://s.mreq.eu/1409307498.png

Comment: Thank you very muck,when I add Indicator Plugin on my panel,All icons appear,both `fcitx`and `xfce4-power-manager`. I want `xfce4-power-manager` shows in Notification Area actually, but it does not matter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you have both Notification Area and Indicator Plugin on your panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Adding Notification Area applet to the panel started showing the Network Indicator. I, however, didn't need to add Indicator plugin nor did it help anyway

Comment: Woah, thanks man! that did the trick :)

Answer (score 24):

For the benefit of further readers having the same problem I would like to note that I managed to get the indicators to show up in the xfce4 indicator area without using the indicator plugin.

[image: screenshot showing the indicator and startup sequence]

I fiddled with the settings, but I think the key point was to *deactivate the gnome indicators* that I marked with red in the screen shot. I reckon these are gnomish programs that might indeed need the indicator-plugin. As can be seen at the top right of the screen shot, at least the network manager and the power indicator appear. Whether there is something special for bluetooth in xfce4, I don't know.

Comment: This solves the problem for me. I disabled those applications from automatic start, and network icon appeared again. I even disinstalled the indicator plugin, since I don't need it.

Comment: Nice, this made all other indicators pop up in the xfce4-indicator-area too!

Comment: worked also for me with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Xfce 4.12. Thanks for the tip! I also have to add that the idea of adding the xfce4-indicator-plugin is not good: you get further unity crap in the sleek minimal xfce bar.

Answer (score 10):

Test this:

Edit /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop:

```
sudo su 
nano /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
```

Go down to the Exec line.

Change the entry:

```
nm-applet
to 
dbus-launch nm-applet
```

Save the file -- Control + O

Close nano -- Control + X

Reboot.

Login and you will see that the n-m icon is now back.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,the network manager icon has appeared,but the fcitx icon is not,I try to add `dbus-launch` to `/etc/xdg/autostart/fcitx-autostart.desktop`,but It does not work.Then i execute fcitx-autostart,it prompts that it is already running，but when I execute the `sudo xfce4-power-manager`,the power manager icon appear.

Comment: This is my `session and startup`setting    https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJnwGgaIrvZbXBPelB6UF9iajg/edit?usp=sharing . I guess these problems may be related to `session and startup`

Comment: when I add Indicator Plugin on my panel,All icons appear,both fcitxand xfce4-power-manager,thank you again

Comment: This doesn't work on Linux Mint Xfce 19. Any ideas?

Comment: Found out the system theme was just making it difficult to see. Switched to Mint-Y, and I could see it just fine.

Comment: For me I didn't have to restart, just open a terminal, run the command, then close the terminal. After editing the launcher, the applet auto-restarts once the terminal is closed. ;)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I needed to install network-manager, and network-manager-gnome, despite the fact that I use using xfce4.

```
sudo apt install network-manager
sudo apt install network-manager-gnome
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
```

I rebooted the system, and the network manager plugin appeared in XFCE4's tray.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the tip with **network-manager-gnome**. Strangely, the xfce4-netload plugin no longer displayed anything, so WLAN could no longer be used.
As described, the applet installed. Reboot. Works.
MX XFCE 23 Libretto

`sudo apt install network-manager-gnome`

`sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service`

network manager was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can also make the network-manager applet show up with systemd, just make sure you have a notification area set

- make a file `~/.config/systemd/user/nm-applet.service` with the following content:
- ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Network Manager Applet

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-applet

  [Install]
  WantedBy=graphical-session.target
  ```
- start it with `systemctl --user start nm-applet`